# Highlight cells in a row where the value of a particular cell is different to that of the previous row

Tags: excel, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I'd like to apply some conditional formatting where each cell of a row is compared to the cell in the previous row.  If it differs then the row is highlighted.

[image: Example of desired output]

I'm using Excel 2007.  Is this even possible?  If so could someone provide me with the steps to apply this to an entire table of data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It was possible in previous versions of Excel, too.

The condition is very simple.

Select the data, starting from the second row of data (the third row counting from the header), bring up the condition formatting dialog, select "Formula" and enter <s>`=A3<>A2`</s>, `=A3<>OFFSET(A3,-1,0)` where `A3` is the top-left cell of the selection.
Note the absence of dollar signs - Excel will automatically suggest them, so delete accordingly.

Because the reference is not absolute, the formatting will properly apply to the whole table.

Comment: This formula suffers from the problem that if a cell or row is inserted into the conditionally formatted range, the row/previous row relationship is broken around the insert.  Using `=A3<>OFFSET(A3,-1,0)` will survive an insert

Answer (score 1):

You can make it even more versatile, like this:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()))<>INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN()))
```

Here's how it works:

- `=ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())` refers to the current cell (i.e. the one to be formatted).
- Similarly, `=ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN())` refers to the cell above the current cell. Then all I do is compare the two.