# Excel 2010 VBA: Set the color of a cell reference cell in previous column

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting, excel-2010

I have  macro that populates a sheet, and copies values into a grid. I want to add conditional formatting to the cells, so that when they are updated if they become greater than the previous column they turn red, smaller they turn green and become 0 they turn grey.

My problem is adding the condition and referenceing the cell.

```
Set newCell = originalEstimateCell.Offset(0, 2 + i)
newCell.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="XX"
newCell.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

My question is what replaces the XX to refer to the previous column in the same row, ie. if we are in Cell C7 I want to refer to cell B7.

Thanks

Comment: You will probably find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194286/highlight-cells-in-a-row-where-the-value-of-a-particular-cell-is-different-to-tha) useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
Sub test()
    ActiveCell.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
                      Formula1:="=" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Address()
    ActiveCell.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)    
End Sub
```

The code above states that the current cell value should be greater than the value of the Formula1, and the formula itself is the address of the cell one column before the active cell. If you want some other cell to be formatted, relatively to the active cell, just change the paramters of the offset method.

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is what replaces the XX to refer to the previous column in the same row, ie. if we are in Cell C7 I want to refer to cell C6.

C6 would be the previous **row** to C7, not the previous column

Try

```
=INDIRECT("C" & ROW()-1)
```

to get the value from the previous row

Comment: Please don't use INDIRECT unless you absoultely have to. It makes the cell volatile (recalculated on every change of any cell in any opened workbook).

Comment: Sorry, I did mean column, I've corrected the main post. Also, I don't know at design time what the cell will be, as I'm generating a large grid.